# Cross domain access to a HikVision camera snapshot - Need to get basic authentication done programatically in classic asp/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp-classic, webcam

I have the following code that once logged in manually, will pull back the camera image with no problem. How do I programmatically login to the camera?

```
<img src="http://<<IP ADDRESS HERE>>:881/Streaming/channels/201/picture?TheTimeIs=<%=request.querystring("Random")%>" 
    style="box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #808080;border: 1px solid #484848;max-width:300px;max-height:250px;display:block;height:auto;width:auto;margin:auto;" 
    title="Current Camera Image at <%=now() %>" />
```

I tried some Javascript AJAX, but it fails due to cross-domain access. I do not have access to the camera server to enable CORS.

This was the AJAX I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebCamResults(intClass) {
    var xmlhttp;

    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    //xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("WebCamResultDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://<<IP ADDDRESS HERE>>:881/Streaming/channels/201/picture", true, "admin", "12345");
    xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU=");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<div id="WebCamResultDiv" style="display:inline;">
</div>
<hr />
<input type="button" value="Refresh Image JS" onclick="WebCamResults();" />
```

Help!

Answer (score 1):

In HTML File Directly capture image form IP Camera

```
<img name="img1" style="-webkit-user-select: none; cursor: zoom-in;" src="http://username:password@cameraip/Streaming/channels/1/picture?videocodec=jpeg" width="200" height="200">
```

Using PHP copy and save particular Place

$file = 'http://username:password@cameraip/Streaming/channels/1/picture?videocodec=jpeg';
   $newfile = 'FileUpload/WBcam1/'.$fnm3.'.jpeg';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
      echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
   }else{echo "failed to copy $newfile...\n";}

Please check it works different browser in differently.